# Windows 10 task manager doesn't show process with high CPU uasge

Tags: windows-10, cpu, performance, cpu-usage, task-manager

while ago I noticed that CPU usage is high even the sound of my laptop fan increases but when i open the task manager to detect the Process that consumes CPU usage the task manager shows me that the task manager consumes all that CPU power usage like the photo

and here is a screenshot of my task manager

the question is how to detect the true process that consumes the CPU because ending the task manger itself can't solve the problem

[image]

Comment: In this example it's task manager itself. I some times see this right after I open it, it drops quickly though.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and indicate in clear and specific detail, what your question is, because as it's currently written your question is not clear.

Comment: Ok i edited my question and its (how to detect the true process that consumes the CPU)